# Always allow orphans and widows

Tags: widows-orphans

I have a simple question, yet I can't find an answer anywhere.

I simply want to *always* allow orphan and widow lines.

Here's what I've done:

- Set `\widowpenalty=0` and `\clubpenalty=0`.
- Use `\flushbottom`.
- Now, LaTeX tried to still fix orphans and widows by adding insane amounts of spacing between paragraphs and below titles whenever it deemed it necessary.
- I fixed this by manually changing all these spacing settings to `... plus 0 minus 0`.

Now we're back to the start. LaTeX still disallows orphan and widow lines and just ditches one line at the bottom of a page to achieve this. I'm writing a book, so I want all pages to be equal in height (as is the case with all books).

I really don't care about orphans or widows, yet LaTeX still disallows them even for new paragraphs which are just newlines+indents (e.g. before a quote in a conversation). How can I achieve this (and why is it so difficult since all books have this)?

My source (as minimal as possible):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{trajan}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}

\usepackage[all]{nowidow}

\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.5}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat*{\section}{\large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\bfseries}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\centering}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\LARGE}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-20pt}{30pt}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{2em plus 0em minus 0em}

\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\newcommand{\q}[1]{>>\textit{#1}<<}

\setlength{\parskip}{0em plus 0em minus 0em}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\widowpenalty=0
\clubpenalty=0
\flushbottom

% Content

\end{document}
```

Comment: Make an example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).  As Ulrike suggested, iIt would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem.  You can use the `lipsum` or `blindtext` package for dummy text.

Comment: Added the source!

Comment: Just get rid of the nowidow package!

Comment: @JohnKormylo My god how didn't I spot that. That worked, thank you! I you can put that in an answer, I'll mark it solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what the nowidow package does, but it goes beyond penalties.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{trajan}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}

%\usepackage[all]{nowidow}% removed

\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.5}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat*{\section}{\large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\bfseries}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\centering}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\LARGE}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-20pt}{30pt}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{2em plus 0em minus 0em}

\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\newcommand{\q}[1]{>>\textit{#1}<<}

\setlength{\parskip}{0em plus 0em minus 0em}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\widowpenalty=0
\clubpenalty=0
\flushbottom

% Content

\end{document}
```